# How to change text on a Label after a button click, in MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, view, label, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have a MVVM Light WPF project that I'm working on.

I want to update the text via binding on the label when a button is clicked.
Not really sure how to do this within the view model.

Below is a look at my view code and view model code. Basically, I want to update the label with the `ProjectStatus` binding to say `Project Created` after the `Create New Project' button is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<Button Content="Create New Project" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding AddProjectCommand}" Width="243"/>
<Label Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="{Binding ProjectStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="325"/>
```

Here is the Model Code:

```
    public RelayCommand AddProjectCommand { get; set; }

    public ProjectConfigViewModel()
    {
        _projectStatus = "Project not created";
        this.AddProjectCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddProject());
    }

    public void AddProject()
    {
        DatabaseInteraction.CreateProjectDb(_projName);
        isProjectLoaded = false;
    }

    public string ProjectStatus
    {
        get { return _projectStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _projectStatus)
            {
                _projectStatus = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("ProjectStatus");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just like that?

```
public void AddProject()
{
    DatabaseInteraction.CreateProjectDb(_projName);
    isProjectLoaded = false;
    ProjectStatus = "Project Created";
}
```